# Google IMAP on android with OAuth2

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, gmail-imap

I'm trying to get messages from **imap.gmail.com**.

First, I get an authtoken from AccountManager:

```
public static String[] getAuthToken(String scope){
    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(MyApp.getAppContext());
    accountManager.invalidateAuthToken("com.google", null);

    Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccounts();
    Account myAccount = null;
    Bundle options = null;

    String[] resultStrings = new String[2];
    String username = null;
    String userToken = null;

    for (Account account : accounts) {

        if (account.type.equalsIgnoreCase("com.google")){

            Log.v(android.content.Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE, "Get account..");

            myAccount = account;

            username = myAccount.name;

            options = new Bundle();

            AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future = accountManager.getAuthToken(
                    myAccount,                      // Account retrieved using getAccountsByType()
                    scope,                          //"oauth2:https://mail.google.com",
                    options,                        // Authenticator-specific options
                    StartActivity.getActivity(),    // Your activity
                    new OnTokenAcquired(),          // Callback called when a token is successfully acquired
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper(), new OnError()));

            try {
                Bundle bundle = future.getResult();
                userToken = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
            } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (AuthenticatorException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    resultStrings[0] = username;
    resultStrings[1] = userToken;

    return resultStrings;
}
```

Scope here - "oauth2:https://mail.google.com"
After that, I use this lib: http://www.mannaz.at/codebase/imap-ssl-mail-android/ to open IMAPStore:

```
IMAPStore store = null;
try {
store = OAuth2Authenticator.connectToImap(
    "imap.gmail.com", 
    993, 
    username, 
    userToken, 
    true);
Log.v("notification", "Connected");
} catch (Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I get the error:

> "javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [ALERT] Invalid credentials (Failure)".

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
Oh, all working fine, maybe, it's just trouble on auth server..